# passing evaluated xpath to extension

Tags: python, xslt, xpath, lxml

I'm working with lxml python lib.

Assuming we have product xml such as:

```
<product id='123' />
```

And want to apply xsl template:

```
<xsl:template match="product">
    <ssi:include virtual="/ssi/reviews/{@id}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

ssi:include is a simple lxml extension that inserts nginx ssi instructions as comments in HTML code. Problem is to evaluate @id and pass attribute as virtual="/ssi/include/123". Is there a way?
I've found a solution and using it by now:

```
import lxml.etree
import re
from copy import deepcopy

ns = '{ssi}'

# ssi extensions
class SsiExtElement(lxml.etree.XSLTExtension):
    def execute(self, context, self_node, input_node, output_parent):
        _, tag = self_node.tag.split('}')
        tmp = lxml.etree.Element('tmp')
        for k, v in self_node.attrib.items():
            if re.search('\{(.*)\}', v): #here we search {xpath} values to evaluate
                elem = deepcopy(input_node)
                matches = re.findall('\{(.*)\}', v)
                for match in matches:
                    v = v.replace('{%s}' % match, elem.xpath(match)[0])
            tmp.set(k, v)
        self.process_children(context, output_parent=tmp)
        attrs = ' '.join(u'%s="%s"' % (k, v) for k, v in tmp.attrib.items())
        ssi = lxml.etree.Comment(u'#%s %s' % (tag, attrs))
        output_parent.append(ssi)
        for node in tmp:
        output_parent.append(node)
        if (self_node.tag.replace(ns,'') in ('if', 'else', 'elif')
            and self_node.getnext().tag.replace(ns, '') not in ('else', 'elif')):
        output_parent.append(lxml.etree.Comment(u'#endif'))
```

Answer (score 1):

try with xsl:attribute

```
<xsl:template match="product">
    <ssi:include>
       <xsl:attribute name="virtual">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('/ssi/reviews/',@id)"/>
       <xsl:attibute>
    </ssi:include>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes, thanx. Thus solution works, but not so neat as I need to implement. In this case we don't need extension at all, writing custom xsl:comment

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation and from what I see I can follow two paths:

- Use `context.context_node`: it's a plain `etree.Element` and has `xpath()`. Logically it's same as `input_node`. This way you can evaluate any XPath in the source document.
- Pass parameters via child elements and use `process_children()` to evaluate them.

Example:

```
<ssi:include>
  <virtual value="/ssi/reviews/{@id}" />
</ssi:include>
```

The second approach allows you you evaluate XSLT variables as well, i.e., in my case:

```
<path:make-directory>
  <target value="{$target}" />
</path:make-directory>
```

All the rest, especially `apply_templates()` doesn't seem to work.